# Getting a list of people who liked a URL with Facebook like button

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'm trying to find the list user ids who clicked on the liked a url address via Facebook Like button.

What I have found so far is that, I can use FQL to get the like information for a facebook object like this:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id = 123
```

With this query I can find the user_id list who like and object. Therefore i need to find the object_id of the url using this query:

```
SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url = 'http://localhost/facebook_page.html'
```

However when I put the returned id to the first query, no result is returned. I have also looked at the url_like table, however I cannot query url column as it's not indexed.

I have found from somewhere else that I have to add fb:admins tag, and force the administrator to like the link for an "open graph page node" to be created in the Graph. I tried that but it did not seemed to work. I don't know how I can check if the "page node" is created or not because I was not able to find any references at all.

user_like table does not work for me, as I cannot use the url column on the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/250668685029065

It seems like it's not possible for now.